# quick search using quick silver?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, quicksilver

just got my first mac os computer.

installed quick silver. (I rely heavily on launchy in windows)

so, the cool feature i was able to achieve on windows using launchy, is that after saving "quick search" i can search any site before even opening the browser.

i.e.

alt+space "g (tab) mac forum"

this will open my browser with search results for "mac forum"

this is because i saved google quick search under "g" but it will also work with any other search i.e. "a" for amazon "wp" for wikipedia etc..

how can i recreate this in mac os?

Answer (score 2):

This is easy and commonly done in Quicksilver.

Make sure you have the newest Web Search plug-in from qsapp.com.

There are some predefined searches you can use, or you can add your own. Look around page 90 of [the manual](http://mysite.verizon.net/hmelman/Quicksilver.pdf). You might also want to see [this post](http://lovequicksilver.com/post/5064746658/searching-the-web-even-quicker-with-quicksilver).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a straight answer, but a quick one.
You might want to quickly look at Alfred app, it has a few quick tools there.

I used it but have not made a full used of what it has to offer yet.

[image: Alfred Web Search Items]
[image: Alfred Web Search Preferences]

Comment: thanks, yah i def checked out alfred and love it. but it doesn't quite do this. it can index safari links.. but it wouldn't do the quick search..

Comment: Yes it does. Your three built in requests (Google, Amazon, Wikipedia) are the default. And there are so many more, and more are ridiculously easy to add.